# Win 10 Error with 'Multiple active Partitions'

Tags: windows-10, boot

I am facing an issue during boot with my Acer Aspire E 15 with 4gb ram. When I start my laptop I get black screen saying 'Multiple active partitions' and below it says
'No Bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key'. I already had OS as win 10.
Do anyone know how to solve this  error

Answer (score 0):

The MBR partition table has a setting that is used to mark one of the primary partitions on the disk as "active", i.e. to be used for booting the system. Apparently your system's BIOS checks for that and will boot from the hard disk only if *exactly one* partition has been marked as active.

Boot from any external media that has a tool that can modify partition tables, e.g. [e.g. a GParted Live CD/USB.](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)
Use that tool to make sure that the partition table has not been corrupted, and if more than one partition has been marked as active, remove the unnecessary mark.

Note that [Windows 10 normally uses more than one partition, even on MBR-partitioned disks.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions) The partition that should be marked as bootable will be the smaller "system partition", **not** the partition that appears as "drive C:" in Windows.

If you find that the partition table has been corrupted any more severely than that, **stop**. If you have anything important on the laptop, you should make a backup image of the complete disk before trying to fix it in any way. If the data on the disk is very valuable to you, you might consider contacting data recovery professionals rather than trying to fix it yourself.

However, if *only* the partition table has been corrupted, [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) will very likely be able to easily reconstruct it.

Comment: Thank you @telcoM but my laptop does not boots so how should I will be able to use the tools to make my laptop run as single OS based.

Comment: Go to another computer (friend/workplace/library?), use it to prepare a bootable USB stick with the tool. Also search for YouTube videos with "Acer Aspire E 15 how to access bios": basically plug in the USB stick, power on the laptop and immediately start repeatedly tapping the F2 key. Change BIOS settings to make the USB stick the 1st boot priority, save settings and reboot. Now you can use the tool with your laptop.

Comment: Thank you again @telcoM I did the above steps I am unable to identify the which is the active partition, and how to remove the other active partition which does not contains OS and run make only one which has OS as primary

Comment: I was trying to use dual booting which I went to disk management and created partition in logical drive as H: @telcoM

Comment: In GParted, look at the right-most column (named "Flags"). Only one partition on the disk should have a "boot" flag on it. If you see two of them, remember which ones they are, select one of the partitions with the "boot" flag, click the right mouse button and select "Manage flags". There you can turn the boot flag off (or back on again if necessary).